# Windows Administrator account constantly changes password

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords, administrator

I had a bit of trouble with my PC lately, so I activated the Admin account and wanted to login to it, but I found out it was password protected. So I thought a quick `net user administrator *` would do it, but it turns out that didn't do it. The password was simply wrong. I also tried using `net user administrator /passwordreq:no`. It said that the command was executed successfully, but I still needed a password. I checked the admin password afterwards and found out it was a completely different string of numbers, letters and symbols. How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first Windows 10 Account is a member of the Administrators Group. You do not need to enable the built in Admin account to solve anything.

You should disable the account and just use your own account

If you need to solve something to disable the built in account, follow this article for using the admin account.

> How to enable the Windows 10 Administrator account using the command
> prompt Enabling the Administrator account using the command prompt is
> the quickest and easiest method.
>
> Open a command prompt as an administrator by typing cmd in the search
> field.  From the results, right-click the entry for Command Prompt,
> and select Run as Administrator.  At the command prompt, type net user
> administrator. The value for Account Active should say No (Figure A).
> Type net user administrator /active:yes. You should receive a response
> that the command completed successfully. Type net user administrator.
> The value for Account Active should now say Yes (Figure B).
>
> [Enable built in Admin](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-administrator-account-in-windows-10/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20enable%20the%20Windows%2010%20Administrator%20account,%2Factive%3Ayes.%20...%206%20Type%20net%20user%20administrator.%20)

Should you need to create a new Account, you can do that.

(1) Be sure to log into the existing account (I assume you can), back up all the data, email, favorites and so on to a USB drive.

(2) Log into the Admin account, make a new Account and make it a member of the Administrators group.

Comment: I see. So I can just create another account and elevate it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, you can do that and I amended my answer to include this.